# Django Contact Form Inputs Won't Show Up - Only See Submit Button

Tags: python, django, forms, contacts

I am running into some trouble here as I attempt setting up a contact form on my personal webpage. For whatever reason I can only see the submit button, the rest of the input fields are not populating. Can someone please help? Thanks!

email.html

```
 {% load static %}
 {% block content %}



 <div id='paddingtop'>
 <div class="row" id="title">
    <div class="col"><img src='{% static 'personal/img/contactme.png' %}' style="height: 100%; width: 100%; max-width: 530px; max-height: 1000px; min-height:500; min-width: 300px;">
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>


 <div class="col"  style='margin-top: -40px;  max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;'><hr class='underline'></div>

<div class='email'  style='background-color: blue; width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
<form method="post" role="form" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" style='background-color: red;'>Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
 </div>



{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^header/$', views.header, name='header'),
    url(r'^email/$', views.email, name='email'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),

   ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')

def test(request):
 return render(request, 'personal/test.html')

def header(request):
 return render(request, 'personal/header.html')


# send_email/views.py
def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})


def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

Comment: No error reports?

Comment: Nope, didn't receive any

Comment: Try `{{ form.fieldname }}` to see if individual fields can be rendered.

Comment: where is your email.html? means can you give the directory structure of the templates?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap 2? Class **form-actions** exists in Bootstrap 2, doesn't in Bootstrap 3. In addition, I don't know what **col** class is.